# Ajax+servlet+unix failed

Tags: jquery, ajax, unix, servlets, tomcat6

I developed a jsp page with jQuery + ajax to submit data to AdmitServlet.
It run ok in my localhost tomcat7, but can not work in unix tomcat6.

code in jsp:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {           
        $('input[type=radio]').click(function() {
            var rateId = $("[name='rateId']").val();
            $.ajax({
              type:"Post",
              url: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/admission/AdmitServlet", 
              data: {action : $("[name='action']:checked").val() , rateId:rateId}, 
              success: function(data){
                $('#welcometext').text(data);
                },
        });
            });
```

this is the error from Chrome:

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:8080/admission/AdmitServlet  jquery-1.10.2.js:8706
sendjquery-1.10.2.js:8706
jQuery.extend.ajaxjquery-1.10.2.js:8136
(anonymous function)list_admit.jsp:49
jQuery.event.dispatchjquery-1.10.2.js:5095
elemData.handlejquery-1.10.2.js:4766
```

Please help me, I am totally confused about it.

Comment: Where exactly are you getting this output in the Chrome Dev Tools? That does not look like any error I have ever seen.

Comment: @thatidiotguy: That's a JS stack trace. You will see that when you unfold the JS error message in console. It's similar to a Java stack trace. OP unfortunately forgot to copypaste the actual JS error message itself.

Comment: @BalusC I was just remarking that there should be an error message.

Answer (score 0):

```
url: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/admission/AdmitServlet",
```

You should never hardcode a localhost based domain URL anywhere in client side code. This won't ever work when you publish the web application in world wide web and the client (the webbrowser) runs at a physically different machine than the server. The `http://127.0.0.1` (and `http://localhost`) URLs are referring to the **current machine**. It's thus trying to hit the server which runs at physically the same machine as where JS code runs (the webbrowser). It would only work when both the webbrowser and webserver runs at physically the same machine, like as when you're locally developing.

Make it at least a domain-relative URL instead.

```
url: "/admission/AdmitServlet",
```

The hardcoded context path `/admission`, is also a source of concern, but not for the current problem. You'll hit it sooner or later.